# Как в строку поместить какое-то число в виде элемента?

Tags: c++

Задача такая: человек задает какую-то цифру с клавиатуры (допустим, 5) и число (допустим, 625). Программа должна вычислить: есть ли во втором числе введенная цифра. Сделать это нужно с использованием строк. Только я не знаю, как? По идее, нужно цифру внести в одну строку, а число - в другую. А потом сравнить по циклу элементы второй строки с элементом первой. Но как?
Как число 625 поместить в строку, чтоб каждая цифра была отдельным элементом? Я пробовала каждую цифру по отдельности занести, но так не получается - элементу строки нельзя присвоить значение переменной, под которой подразумевается цифра.

Comment: Когда человек вводит число - он вводит **строку** - так и читайте ее как строку!

Comment: Окей. А если я не ввожу число, а оно просто у меня изначально будет в виде перемнной, как его внести в строку?

Comment: @Дмитрия, тогда `sprintf`или `ostringstream`.

Comment: А можно конкретнее? Часть кода присвоения элементу строки какой-нибудь переменной?

Comment: @Дмитрия использовать [string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), функцию [to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) и метод [string::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

char(5 + '0')  есть символ '5'

чтобы было понятнее, вот код без библиотечных функций

```
int n = 625, m = 5, k = n,   sz1 = 1;
while(k) {
    ++sz1;
    k /= 10;
}

char array1[sz1],
        c = m + '0';
for (int i = 0; i < sz1; ++i) {
    array1[i]  = n % 10 + '0';
    n /= 10;
}
for (int i = 0; i < sz1; ++i)
    if (array1[i] == c)
        cout << "ok";
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но я немного не дождалась вашего ответа и нашла решение самостоятельно))
Оказывается, переменную (цифру) нужно было переделать в символ, а потом "присуммировать" к строке